# Como enviar imagens em um relatório FastReport com Delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi, imagem, pdf, fast-reports

eu estava com muitas dúvidas a respeito. Pesquisei durante dias diversos artigos a respeito, mas em todos eu vi uma falha, a maioria não mostrava de forma clara como enviar um parâmetro ou variável do código em Delphi para o ambiente de execução do FastReport. Nem mesmo na vasta documentação do componente FastReport e nos fóruns dela encontrei algo claramente, só depois de encontrar um bom artigo próximo da solução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813438/how-to-verify-that-a-file-exists-in-fastreport-4

Enfim, usando o método "tentativa e erro" (rss) com a dica acima, acabei resolvendo a questão, e como sei que muitos estão ou acabam tendo o mesmo problema, vou postar a solução que consegui fazer e quem sabe colaborar com outros que tenham tido dúvidas semelhantes:

no meu projeto, uma aplicação em Delphi para Web, usando componentes IntraWeb, no evento AsyncClick do botão "IMPRIMIR" eu exporto o relatório em formato PDF:

```
procedure TF_produtos.bt_imprimirAsyncClick(Sender: TObject; EventParams: TStringList);
var
  objExportfilter : TfrxCustomExportFilter;
begin
  objExportfilter := TfrxCustomExportFilter(frx_PDF);
  objExportfilter.ShowDialog := False;
  objExportfilter.FileName := GetCurrentDir + '\wwwroot\impressos\frx_produtos.pdf';

//passando como parâmetro a variável 'img_path' o caminho da aplicação e o diretório das imagens salvas..
  frx_produtos.Variables['img_path'] := frx_produtos.GetApplicationFolder+'wwwroot\produtos\'; 

  frx_produtos.PrepareReport(True);
  frx_produtos.Export(objExportfilter);
  WebApplication.CallBackResponse.AddJavaScriptToExecute('window.open("/impressos/frx_produtos.pdf");');
end;
```

e aqui no design do FastReport, no evento OnBeforePrint da banda MasterData1 incluí estas linhas onde eu recupero a informação passada em img_path e o nome do arquivo de imagem ao componente img_produto que será inserido no relatório impresso.

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
  arquivo: string;                                                             
begin
  arquivo := report.Variables['img_path']+<frx_dbdataset."IMAGEM">;                                                                            
  img_produto.Picture.LoadFromFile(arquivo);
end;
```

resultado (imagens):

[image: relatório com imagens]
[image: ajustando o FastReport em tempo de desing do relatório]
[image: referenciando o caminho "img_path" das imagens salvas antes de carregar o relatório]

Galera, essa foi a forma que encontrei para resolver o problema, mas espero que (segundo as normas aqui) o pessoal do Stack-Overflow) permitam eu compartilhar
e ajudar outros que tiveram a mesma dúvida e que como eu não encontrou respostas completas, claras ou objetivas. (fiz como pede asinstruções aqui, descrevi a pergunta, colei uma parte do código (os trechos mais relevantes) e acredito que não haja nenhum outro critério que esteja faltando, rss

Bom, por enquanto é só, quem quiser comentar ou sugerir algo, fiquem a vontade, rss. Abraços, Ezequias =O)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Boa tarde ezequias martins.. Tudo certinho?? Cara realmente nunca passei por esse problema com o FAST REPORT, mas caso eu passe , já sei como resolver.. Obrigado por postar uma solução. Abraços :)

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo! 
O fato é que quando eu pesquisei antes, não estava encontrando nenhum exemplo claro, nenhum exemplo explicava como definir e passar o parâmetro do lado do código no Delphi, não encontrei nem na documentação do Fast-Report exemplo completo (o que faz muitas perguntas ficarem sem respostas, rss) e acabei tendo que sacar sozinho no velho método "tentativa-erro-e-acertos" até dar certo, kkk mas para publicar a dica, tive que enviar como se fosse uma pergunta (regras do site) a única forma de fazê-lo aqui no Stack, rsrsrs